# Loading Page Into Div : Accessing Parent Page Elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am loading a page one.html into a div present on the site two.html

And I am using a separate javascript file to handle the workings of two.html
But in that case , I am unable to access the elements of the page one.html and hence any action related to them, I cannot perform unless I script it directly into one.html

But if so , I cannot access the parent page elements in the script in one.html

The only problem being that I need to access the elements of both files one.html and two.html in a single javascript file which I am unable to do.

Any suggestions wherein this could be done ?

Comment: if you are loading the one.html with an ajax call you can make use of the "success:function(){}"

Comment: So suppose i load one.html as $("#wrapper").load("one.html");
then within the success function will I be able to access all of the html tags of one.html ?